# Where to put RESTful many-to-many logic in MVC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rest, many-to-many, crud

for example a have simple rails app with two models, users and books. now i what to let the user save books to their favorites list. where do i put the logic (users_controller?) to make it RESTful?

Comment: Logic for what? From your description, you also have a favourites model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routes file could look like this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :favorites, only=>[:index, :create, :destroy]
end
resources :books
```

That way when you add a book to a users' favorite, you post to create a new user_favorite.